# How to rotate a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, rotation, spinning

I have a UIImageView that is an image of the star. The problem is I want the star to rotate when I move it. How can I rotate a UIImageView to make it look like it is spinning for 3 seconds. I want it to spin 720 degrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a very simple approach, you can use

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radianRotation);
```

where `radianRotation` is a float, e.g. 4*pi for 720 degrees. You can play with basic animations and changing the rotation however you like.

However, if you want a more sophisticated solution, then I highly recommend you look at the answers to this related post: [how to rotate UIIMageVIew with fix point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414923/how-to-rotate-uiimageview-with-fix-point)

Also, see the myriad related posts linked on the right hand side of your screen. Many have all the code you need (barring going around in a circle twice).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
[imageView layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your commodity, additionally to PengOne's answer you can use M_PI, M_PI_2, M_PI_4 constants that are available in math.h.