# How to rotate an image by some angle which is set by programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipad, image-rotation

Currently I am fetching a random image from the iPad image library and showing it in UIImageView. I want to rotate it by some predefined angle which I can set.

I don't want any touch based rotation. How can I do that?

Comment: refer the following links. You can get some ideas to rotate a image. 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852863/how-can-i-rotate-an-uiimageview-by-20-degrees 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414923/how-to-rotate-uiimageview-with-fix-point 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rotate an UIImageView by 20 degrees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852863/how-can-i-rotate-an-uiimageview-by-20-degrees)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just rotate the UIImageView?
Include QuartzCore framework.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

self.imageView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
```

See the documentation on [`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation)

Answer (score 1):

```
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( rotateValue ) );
myObject.transform = rotateTransform;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one:

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)(90 * M_PI / 180.0));

self.imageView.transform = newTransform;
```

Here 90 in degree, You can use another angle.